# Pear Mail corrupting php file

Tags: php, email, pear

When I try to include PEAR's Mail.php, it breaks my code.

I have installed PEAR properly (followed the instructions on the PEAR site and received proper output code) and added an include_path in the php.ini to PEAR for when I need to include the package. Basically all instructions on how to install properly were followed to a T.

Why would including PEAR's Mail.php break my code unrelated to PEAR?  Even when I have nothing pertaining to PEAR's Mail.php besides the include (or require_once), my other code breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a variable/object conflict of some kind.  You might be redefining something unintentionally that has already been defined in the PEAR Mail include.  Without seeing the code it is hard to say.

Comment: My code is as follows:
<?php
include "Mail.php";
$to="xxx@domain.com";
$subject="Request to Reset EduTube Password";
$body="Thank you ".$to." for using the EduTube Password Reset System.\n\n";
$from="xxx@domain.org";
$server="exchange.domain.org";
$port="25";
$username="user";
$password="password";
$headers=array('From'=>$from,'To'=>$to,'Subject'=>$subject);
$smtp=Mail::factory('smtp',array('host'=>$server,'port'=>$port,'auth'=>true,'username'=>$username,'password'=>$password));
$mail=>$smtp->send($to,$headers,$body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)){
echo "Error";
}
else {
echo "Success";
}
?>